# howto override contextConfigLocation in dispacherServlet

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets

I want to override the context configLocation

The web.xml as following

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mypackage.MyDispacherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:default-ctx.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then there is MyDispacherServlet

```
public class MyDispacherServlet extends org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet {


@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    // here will be code to find dynamically other-ctx.xml
    String correctSpringXml = "classpath*:other-ctx.xml";
    setContextConfigLocation(correctSpringXml) ;
    super.init(config);
}

@Override
protected WebApplicationContext initWebApplicationContext() throws BeansException {
    WebApplicationContext wac = super.initWebApplicationContext();

    return wac;
}
```

}

But this code doesn't work.
How can I override the contextConfigLocation corretlly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need have a closer look at the `init` method you try to override (defined in `HttpServletBean`).

```
//unimportent parts removed
    @Override
    public final void init() throws ServletException {
            ...
        try {
            PropertyValues pvs = new ServletConfigPropertyValues(getServletConfig(), this.requiredProperties);
            BeanWrapper bw = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(this);
            ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new ServletContextResourceLoader(getServletContext());
            bw.registerCustomEditor(Resource.class, new ResourceEditor(resourceLoader, this.environment));
            initBeanWrapper(bw);
            bw.setPropertyValues(pvs, true);
        }
        catch (BeansException ex) {...}
            ...
        // Let subclasses do whatever initialization they like.
        initServletBean();
            ...
    }
```

It looks that the `contextConfigLocation` paramter is set by `bw.setPropertyValues(pvs, true);`

Different ideas for solutions:

- You need to override the init method complete (without invoking `super.init()`). And then modify `pvs` (how ever you do this) before `bw.setPropertyValues(pvs, true);` is invoked.
- Or you override `initServletBean()`  and modify the property there, before you invoke `super.initServletBean()`.
- **that is what I would try first:**
  Or you try to override `getServletConfig()` so that it returns your modfied configuration.

Comment: I'm probably missing something: I get ServletConfig in init (but I can not update it's properties); I've extended org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet and there is no this.requiredProperties

Comment: @Julias: It is because my posted code is not the solution, but the code of the init method you tryed to override. If you look at this code, and assume that you invoke it (with `super`) after you done `setContextConfigLocation(correctSpringXml)` the it will override the configuration again! -- Therefor you need to find an other way, and the bullet points are suggestions for other ways.

Comment: Thanks you, I'll look for solution. My problem was that the init() get's the ServletConfig and I see in debugger the map with properties of contextConfigLocation, and there is no way to override/change it.

Comment: @Julias Have a look at the code I have posted. And I hope you understoud why your attempt is not working! After you understoud that, go on an read the section I have written about the 3 different ideas how to solve the problem.